# Java Thread Pool Executor Service shutdown not working as expected

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Currently I am using a global instance of Executor Service that is shared around the script. My idea is call and add tasks to the pool for threads to do work on and when ALL the threads are finished, then write to an output file for the results.

A small visual below:
Main thread calls t0, t1, t2, t3 and t0 calls t4, t5. The other threads can call other threads as well.

```
main thread calls:
     openFile()
     -> t0
          -> t4
          -> t5
          ...
     -> t1
     -> t2
     -> t3 
     ...
     shutdown()
     awaitTermination(60, MINUTES)
     writeFile()
     closeFile()
```

The problem is shutdown() and awaitTermination() get called and finish when t0, t1, t2, t3 and doesn't wait for t4 and t5. So the output gets written while t4 and t5 are still completing their tasks. I executed t4 and t5 with the same instance as the others figuring that it would add it to the pool and awaitTermination() would wait for them (along with the other threads that were called by other treads) to finish.

How would I be able to go about this?

Comment: Are t4 and t5 added to the executor? Or are sub threads of the parent thread?

Comment: @LeonardoEmmanueldeAzevedo they are added to the same instance pool via calling execute()

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `shutdown` until you know `t0` is finished - then you will know that t4/t5 must have been queued on the same executor service.

If t0 is a task that you submit to same executor service the flow is something like this:

```
Future<?> t0fut = execService.submit(t0);
// deal with others t1..t3
...
t0fut.get();
execService.shutdown();
...
```

The call to `t0fut.get()` should block until t0 is done, then the call to `execService.shutdown()` won't cause errors as t4/t5 must have already be submitted before `t0` ended.

If t0 is some thread you've kicked off which submits task to executor service, you need to wait for it to end before `execService.shutdown()`, something like:

```
t0.join();
execService.shutdown();
...
```

Comment: Hm, I also want t0 to finish it's task and become free while t4 and t5 keep doing their work. t0 should be ready to do any other task including if t4 calls another thread. Would that still work?

Comment: @efoc Is `t0` a thread performing some action, or is it a task submitted to that same executor service?

Comment: t0 does some task -> calls multiple threads for new tasks and the finishes while the threads it called continue doing work.